# Pings staying undismissed in chat and not getting to the inbox

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat, notifications, ping

I noticed that some chat pings have lasted for hours undismissed, with the ping remaining in chat, but not getting turned into an inbox notification, and also not showing up in search results.

I have two examples. One was [this message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49771286#49771286). I only saw it five hours after being posted, but there was nothing in my inbox.

[image: my inbox]

The other example is [this message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49773101#49773101), where I again did not receive a notification, despite only dismissing the ping nearly an hour after the message was sent.

Also, these pings do not show up if I perform a [search for my username](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=mithrandir):

[image: search results]

All in all, this seems like a bug. Perhaps related to the changes that were being made to chat that Shog hinted about in the Tavern? :)

Comment: Hmm, I seem to be getting notifications now.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there was a scheduler issue that has been resolved.  Messages are move to the inbox in batch via an internal API, so if the scheduler's down they don't get across.

Comment: There seem to be a lot of scheduler problems right now...

Comment: I think it was mostly just one scheduler problem affecting a lot of things.